# How to prevent oracle-xe from automatically launching at startup?

Tags: startup, services, systemd, oracle

I did  a new install of Oracle 11g XE on my Ubuntu 16.04 (
[following this tutorial](http://blog.whitehorses.nl/2014/03/18/installing-java-oracle-11g-r2-express-edition-and-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-64-bit/))

Every thing its up and running.

The problem is: When installing I said not to start at boot.

```
Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:n
```

yet the Oracle continues start on boot.

```
bruno@ubuntu:/etc/init.d$ ps aux | grep oracle
oracle     914  0.0  0.0  45248  4664 ?        Ss   19:12   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
oracle     916  0.0  0.0  63212  1860 ?        S    19:12   0:00 (sd-pam)
oracle    1031  0.0  0.1 224520 20116 ?        Ssl  19:12   0:00 /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -inherit
oracle    1421  0.0  0.2 1268904 46568 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_pmon_XE
oracle    1423  0.0  0.2 1266624 42476 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_psp0_XE
oracle    1563  0.0  0.2 1266624 40556 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_vktm_XE
oracle    1567  0.0  0.2 1266624 40212 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_gen0_XE
oracle    1569  0.0  0.2 1266624 40468 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_diag_XE
oracle    1571  0.0  0.4 1267136 65812 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_dbrm_XE
oracle    1573  0.0  0.2 1267136 44040 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_dia0_XE
oracle    1575  0.0  0.3 1266624 56080 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_mman_XE
oracle    1577  0.0  0.2 1272760 48908 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_dbw0_XE
oracle    1579  0.0  0.3 1282176 50040 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_lgwr_XE
oracle    1581  0.0  0.2 1267136 47848 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_ckpt_XE
oracle    1583  0.0  0.7 1271296 118084 ?      Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_smon_XE
oracle    1585  0.0  0.3 1267136 61848 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_reco_XE
oracle    1587  0.0  0.7 1272556 121628 ?      Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_mmon_XE
oracle    1589  0.0  0.2 1266624 47296 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_mmnl_XE
oracle    1591  0.0  0.2 1274948 39844 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_d000_XE
oracle    1593  0.0  0.2 1267820 37456 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_s000_XE
oracle    1595  0.0  0.2 1267820 37476 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_s001_XE
oracle    1597  0.0  0.2 1267820 37472 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_s002_XE
oracle    1599  0.0  0.2 1267820 37416 ?       Ss   19:12   0:00 xe_s003_XE
oracle    2121  0.1  0.2 1266624 41436 ?       Ss   19:13   0:01 xe_vkrm_XE
oracle    2125  0.0  0.2 1266624 44412 ?       Ss   19:13   0:00 xe_qmnc_XE
oracle    2144  0.0  0.6 1273288 99460 ?       Ss   19:13   0:00 xe_cjq0_XE
oracle    2192  0.0  0.5 1268160 84412 ?       Ss   19:13   0:00 xe_q000_XE
oracle    2194  0.0  0.3 1266620 50516 ?       Ss   19:13   0:00 xe_q001_XE
oracle    2429  0.0  0.2 1266624 40732 ?       Ss   19:18   0:00 xe_smco_XE
oracle    2431  0.0  0.3 1266620 52712 ?       Ss   19:18   0:00 xe_w000_XE
```

/etc/init.d/oracle-xe

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ "$0" != "/etc/init.d/oracle-xe" ]
    then
        if test -f "$CONFIGURATION"
        then
            if test "$ORACLE_DBENABLED" != "true"
            then
                exit 0
            fi
        else
        echo "Oracle Database 11g Express Edition is not configured.  You must run '/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure' as the root user to configure the database."
                exit 0
        fi
    fi
    start
       ;;
```

/etc/default/oracle-xe

```
#This is a configuration file for automatic starting of the Oracle
#Database and listener at system startup.It is generated By running
#'/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure'.Please use that method to modify this 
#file

# ORACLE_DBENABLED:'true' means to load the Database at system boot.
ORACLE_DBENABLED=false

# LISTENER_PORT: Database listener
LISTENER_PORT=1521

# HTTP_PORT : HTTP port for Oracle Application Express
HTTP_PORT=9991

# Configuration : Check whether configure has been done or not
CONFIGURE_RUN=true
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. The following seems to work on 16.04.

To stop the service right now (will not persist after system reboot):

```
sudo systemctl stop oracle-xe
```

To prevent it from launching on next startup (persist after system reboot):

```
sudo systemctl disable oracle-xe
```

To start it again right now (will not persist after system reboot):

```
sudo systemctl start oracle-xe
```

To make it automatically launch on startup (persist after system reboot):

```
sudo systemctl enable oracle-xe
```

More details about `systemctl` are [here on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)

Answer (score 0):

systemctl disable oracle.xe.service 
(if do not start on boot in /etc/default/oracle-xe, /etc/init.d/oracle-xe not working)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details what this is supposed to do. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Could you please clarify this a bit, it is really difficult what exactly that means...